# Property not found on object type of nested type object in Objective - C

Tags: arrays, objective-c, generics, type-conversion

```
@interface MyModel :NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray <MyModel> *items;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *id;

@end
```

---

```
@interface SomeVC ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject *object;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray <MyModel> *items;


 _items = (NSMutableArray <MyModel> *)self.object;
 _items.items // !! COMPILE ERROR
```

**and i am getting error propery not found on object type of `(NSMutableArray <MyModel> *)`**

I work on a very long written classes so i writed some parts of codes.

I am trying to reach items object which has many MyModel object in it. Also inside of this MyModel objects there are a nested seconds items object MyModel type.

I am used to write in Swift. With type casting everything was easy. What is the good approach to type casting in Objective-C. How can give reference object to items and items.items be meaningful ?

Comment: Noooo - in Objective-C it is such a relief that you do not have to type cast everything, although that is of course a matter of taste. Anyhow, you can not use MyModel like that, you must use a pointer to it. Also you need to import the correct header to fix your problem. I'll post some code to illustrate ...

Comment: please sir looking forward to see your answer:) i think header file already implemented in the project.

Comment: I posted how to do the NSMutableArray but not clear on what you are trying to do with items? It is really fishy that you set self.items = self.object? What is going on? The compile error is because there is no ```items``` on a mutable array.

Comment: I am trying your suggestions on the project, give me some times :)

Comment: and going on like
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray<MyModel> *' from 'NSObject *'

Comment: You can have an array inside another array but I don't think you are using the object correctly or maybe I am not understanding. It is difficult to help as this is not an interactive site. I think try a bit more, maybe use ```[self.items addObject:xxx];``` to add objects to the array and once you make some progress ask again if you get stuck.

Comment: rename property "id" to something like "ID" or "identifier". "id" is causing weirdo behaviour for the preprocessor and then even the compiler even tho its actually valid code, but id is a objC keyword and will for sure confuse your preprocessor.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` doesn't have a property `items`. Is `self.object` an array or a `MyModel`? Can `self.object` be some other class? What should be the result of `_items.items`?

Comment: Thank you guys.. Basically i was wrong trying to access like :
_items.items xxx 
secondly i trying to use
_items[0].items again not a good result but for loop with id in items like 
and later i made a for loop catch a object with id and use it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error I *think* you are missing an

```
#import "MyModel.h"
```

in the `SomeVc.m` class.

If you are in a hurry Objective-C is kind enough to allow you to do simply (and much more generally)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * items;
```

with perhaps generating a warning. This just in terms of your type casting comment.

To specifically answer your question you really need a pointer to MyModel here, so change it to

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray < MyModel * > * items;
```

Comment: thanks i followed these, but nothing changed, items array still acting as standart array and dont see its properties

Comment: @ayfer that's the classic moment to use a protocol and store objC "id"'s in a `NSMutableArray<id<YourProtocol>>*items;`. Which is why property naming like "id" is causing trouble in reality. Another troublesome thing could be if you have a method returning a plain NSMutableArray like so `-(NSMutableArray*)items {...}`. instead of `-(NSMutableArray<MyModel*>*)items {...}`